# Anti Packet Inspection Idea

Tags: patentability, internet, protect, network, security

I've got an innovative but simple idea to defeat or avoid SPI (Shallow Packet Inspection) and even DPI (Deep Packet Inspection) as well and can be explained in a single paragraph. Actually it may have many security and anti-censorship applications.

- How can I publish and protect my idea?
- Is there any Company going to pay for just this idea if it can be proved technically practical?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to protect your idea you would get a solid US patent application on file *before* you publish anything about it. You might want to delve more into the practicality of the idea before publishing anything. One approach would be to file first on what you already have in mind and then do more thinking/work on possible implementations and file again on those details before publishing.

I have an acquaintance who says "companies steal ideas but they buy product lines". I'm not sure how true that is but I imagine proving that your scheme is practical and that there is a market of willing customers would enhance its value. Of course, doing a good search to see how novel the idea really is should be one of your first steps.

Comment: Hi Mr. George White. How can I get a solid US patent application? Actually as far as I know, getting US patent is an expensive and lengthy process. You know, I need the money that a willing company is going to pay for my idea as soon as possible. Do you know how can I contact Google directly via email?
Your time and help is appreciated,

Comment: Getting a  patent issued *is* a lengthy and expensive process. Filing an application is the first step and there are trade-offs of cost vs. quality. You can write up your idea with as much detail, diagrams, etc. as possible and submit it as a provisional patent application. The fees are low, especially if you qualify as a micro-entity. Once you file you are in a much better position to approach people. If you have a "one paragraph" idea, after you disclose it what do you have to sell unless you have something on file?